# wp-engine and reactjs headless api returning wrong response

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, wpengine

I am reactjs and wordpress to handle user management. The code I written is working fine in my local wordpress but in wp-engine it is returning my react public/index.html content as response.

I have written custom functions using php to register and login the user. I am accessing those functions using reactjs axios call with relevant api endpoint. Even though it is working perfectly fine in my localhost wordpress setup, It is not working in wp-engine.

**functions.php**

```
function custom_login_user($request){
  $params = $request->get_json_params(); // Retrieve data from the request body.
  $username = sanitize_text_field($params['username']);
  $password = wp_kses_post($params['password']);

  $user = wp_authenticate($username, $password);

  if(is_wp_error($user)){
    return new WP_Error('login_failed', $user->get_error_message(), array('status' => 401));
  }

  // Generate a user token (you may use JWT or any other secure method).
  $access_token_payload = array(
    "user_id" => $user->ID,
    "username" => $user->user_login,
    "email" => $user->user_email,
    "exp" => time() + 3600, // Token expiration time (1 hour from now).
  );

  // Generate the access token using the custom function.
  $access_token = generate_jwt_token($access_token_payload);

  // Generate a refresh token with a longer expiration time (e.g., 30 days from now).
  $refresh_token_payload = array(
    "user_id" => $user->ID,
    "exp" => time() + 2592000, // Refresh token expiration time (30 days from now).
  );

  // Generate the refresh token using the custom function.
  $refresh_token = generate_jwt_token($refresh_token_payload);

  // Save the refresh token for the current user (you may use user meta or any other storage method).
  update_user_meta($user->ID, 'refresh_token', $refresh_token);

  // Return the user details, access token, and refresh token in the response.
  return [
    'email' => $user->user_email,
    'username' => $user->user_login,
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'refresh_token' => $refresh_token,
  ];

}

function custom_login_user_endpoint() {
  register_rest_route('custom/v1', '/login-user', array(
    'methods' => 'POST',
    'callback' => 'custom_login_user',
  ));
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'custom_login_user_endpoint');
```

**ReactJS Axios call**

```
const loginHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const apiEndpoint = `${apiHost}/wp-json/custom/v1/login-user`;
    console.log(email);
    axios
      .post(apiEndpoint, {
        username: email,
        password: password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("User logged in:", response);
        const { data } = response;
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", data.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", data.refresh_token);
        const userInfo = {
          email: data.email,
          name: data.email,
        };
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(userInfo));
        navigate('/')
        // Set the user details and token received from the response.
        // setEmail(response.data.email);
        // setUsername(response.data.username);
        // setUserToken(response.data.user_token);
        // Do something with the response, like displaying a success message.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error logging in:", error);
        // Handle error scenarios, like displaying an error message.
      });
  };
```

**Response**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script src='/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/react-src/node_modules/@devloco/create-react-wptheme-utils/wpThemeClient.js'></script>

<script src='/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/react-src/node_modules/@devloco/create-react-wptheme-utils/wpThemeErrorOverlay.js'></script>

<script> wpThemeClient.start("ws", "127.0.0.1", "8090"); </script>

  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://findmyneighdev.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/favicon.ico" />


  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-wptheme" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/logo192.png" />
  <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
  <link rel="manifest" href="/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/manifest.json" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <!--
        If you're reading this from "view source" in your browser, it might not make sense as
        these tokens have already been evaluated and replaced, even in this remark blurb.

        Notice the use of "php echo $TEMPLATE_PATH;" and /wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme in the tags above.
        Both will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build (/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme) or
        at render time (php echo $TEMPLATE_PATH;)
        Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced like this.

        Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/favicon.ico" will
        work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
        Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run wpbuild`.
    -->
  <title>My Next Neighborhood</title>
<link href="/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/static/css/main.chunk.css?d02c8c7b01d859f67ff0" rel="stylesheet"></head>

<body>
  <noscript>
    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
  </noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
        This PHP file is a template.
        If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

        You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
        The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

        To begin the development, run `npm run wpstart` or `yarn wpstart`.
        To create a production bundle, use `npm run wpbuild` or `yarn wpbuild`.
    -->
<script src="/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/static/js/bundle.js?d02c8c7b01d859f67ff0"></script><script src="/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/static/js/0.chunk.js?d02c8c7b01d859f67ff0"></script><script src="/wp-content/themes/fmn-react-wp-theme/static/js/main.chunk.js?d02c8c7b01d859f67ff0"></script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is likely what you describe: The registration of the API endpoint on WP-Engine. You need to contact support, open an issue with them, there is very little what we can do here about it. See as well [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)